# openfire chat server Daemon not getting started while server starts up every time

Tags: services, init.d

We are using a Chat server It is installed with openfire, for local office use. Every morning while server getting ON openfire service is not getting started, I have added it in run levels too, Using command , `chkconfig` , Operating system we are using is CentOS 6.5 final.

```
chkconfig --level 0123456 openfire on
```

The output of chkconfig was below

```
openfire        0:on    1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:on
```

And still it is not getting started when ever the Server was up and running, Every time I have to start the service manually using

```
/etc/init.d/openfire start
```

So this step has not worked for me, so I edited the rc.local file and added the service too. It too is not working for me

```
vim /etc/rc.local
```

Entered as below in the rc.local

```
sh /etc/init.d/openfire start
```

If any one faces the same issue, please let me know how can I get the fix.

Comment: Which version of `openfire` are you using & what are you getting in the error/warn.log.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to dig to find the root cause. Blindly putting chkconfig on every runlevel is not going to resolve the issue.

1. Check /var/log/messages for startup issues/errors.
2. Put set -x right after #!/bin/sh in /etc/init.d/openfire -- It will debug the script for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question,and solved by [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849199/why-cant-i-get-openfire-to-start)

```
cd /opt/openfire/jre/bin
cp java java.bak
rm java
ln -s /usr/bin/java java
service openfire start
```